# This JQuery Code can be written more elegantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some working JQuery code I've written but I have a feeling I could write is more elegantly but my JQuery knowledge is rusty.

The following code works fine:

```
$('table.displayTable').each(function() {
    $(this).DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "filter": false
    })
});
```

I thought I could write the code like this but it doesn't work...I think there is a way but I'm missing something?

```
$('table.displayTable').each().DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  "filter": false
});

// If I had just one table I can just do this
$('#dataTable').DataTable({ ... });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid to pass a selector which results in multiple elements as can be seen in the [**Multiple tables**](https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html) example which says

> This is trivially done by using a jQuery selector which will pick up
>   multiple tables.

So, you can do

```
$('table.displayTable').DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "filter": false
});
```